# How do you reverse $\frac{100n(n+1)}{2}=c$ to find n given c?

Tags: functions, inverse, quadratics

I'm developing a game where the character experience needed by level is given by Gauss' formula multiplied by 100: $ \dfrac{100\mathrm{level}(\mathrm {level}+1)}{2}$. So the experience table is something like this:

```
level : experience needed

0       0
1       100
2       300
3       600
```

Right now I'm trying to find a way to reverse the formula, and, having the player's experience, find their level. The problem is that I can't seem to find a formula that is not a quadratic equation. Is this even possible?

Comment: It should be $2$ and $3$ in the left column, right?

Comment: It sounds more like a flaw in your game design. When would you ever have access to a players experience but not their level?

Comment: @Jonny why would I save their level if I have their experience? You could argue it's a flaw in the engineering of my code/database, but the player has access to both their experience and their level, so not a game design issue.

Comment: @Luke B. I would recommend storing a table of all levels that are possible to achieve together with the minimum experience required for that level to facilitate conversions to and from level and experience. I would also recommend that any data structures representing players contain a field for their level, but only store experience when necessary.

Comment: @Jonny What problems could arise from not using a table? Right now I can convert from experience to level and back without trouble, I can simply call `player.getLevel()` whenever I need.

Comment: @Luke B. If your game is single player, I suppose it wouldn't matter. But if you have a large number of players, why waste cpu time calculating everyone's levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{x(x+1)}{2}=y\implies (x)(x+1)=2y\implies x^2+x-2y=0\implies\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ x=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+8y}}{2}$$
Where y is $EXP/100$.

Note:This always returns positive and rational $\forall x$ generated using that equation.

Comment: And to get the level reached, take $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks for the edits and thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

A simple quadratic equation:

$$x^2+x-2y=0$$

The solution (I assume you want the positive one only):

$$x = {\sqrt{1+8y}-1\over2}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is a quadratic equation, but it's quite clear that when some $x>0$ is a solution $-(x+1)<0$ is also a solution, so it should be quite simple to only find the positive solution.